# How to embed custom XML elements inside message stanza's in Tsung XML file?

Tags: ejabberd, tsung

How to send the following type of custom modified message stanzas in Tsung?

```
<message from='91_9999111001@localhost/tsung' to='91_9999111000@localhost' id='12' type='chat'>
    <custom_element attr1="val1"></custom_element>
</message>
```

The idea is the sender and receiver must be chosen by Tsung as usual but the `<body>` is removed and `<custom_element>` is added dynamically.

Comment: You got any solution ?